# Access Django Rest Framework API using Javascript - getting a Token

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I have an API setup using Django Rest Framework. It works fine when accessing via cURL or HTTPie or even the browsable API. The API has token authentication so initially you have to supply credentials which will return a token. Using HTTPie (or even curl) you would do this:

```
http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/api-token-auth/ username="user1" password="testpassword"
```

This would return a response e.g.:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 03 Sep 2017 16:57:38 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.1
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "token": "fgfdgfdgfdgfdgd45345345lkjlj"
}
```

You would then take the token and perform a GET/PUSH/etc like so:

```
http --json POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test/ test_text="Testing" 'Authorization: Token fgfdgfdgfdgfdgd45345345lkjlj'
```

I have been Google searching for a while now and cannot find any clear answers as to how the above two lines would translate into Javascript? How do I (1) Pass through credentials to get a token; (2) Retrieve the Token; (3) Use the token to make a GET and PUSH request?

Comment: are you using a particular framework/library?

Comment: Hi @bryan60, i am not using any particular Javascript library. I am happy to use whichever JS library gets the job done.

Comment: you cannot send data in the url, using post method. You need to pass the credentials in the form of key value pairs in the header.

Comment: use jQuery, its easy to use and lots of functionality provided

Comment: @AbhishekParmar appreciate the comment but _how_ exactly do i do this with jquery? Syntactically, what would it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree you should use Ajax.

You need an ajax call in the very beginning of you app:

```
var data = {username:'user',password:'password'}

$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: data,
       url: 'http://your_url',
       success: function(res){
               console.log(res)
               $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                    "token": res.token
                  }
               });
       },
       error: function(error) {
           callbackErr(error,self)
       }
   })
```

Haven`t tested, but idea is use an Ajax call to get the token and use .ajaxSetup to save the token to a header for all following ajax requests.

The you can do this:

```
var data = {test_text="Testing"}
$.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           data: data,
           url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test/',
           success: function(res){
                   console.log(res)  //answer of api call.
                   });
           },
           error: function(error) {
               callbackErr(error,self)
           }
       })
```

Or this:

```
$.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/ANOTHER_TES/',
           success: function(res){
                   console.log(res)  //answer of api call.
                   });
           },
           error: function(error) {
               callbackErr(error,self)
           }
       })
```

Change `type` parameter of the call to change your request.

Comment: Thanks @Tico, so this code returns a token which is great as it answers points 1 and 2 in my question. But it is unclear to me how the token can then be used to make a GET or PUSH request. Can you give a basic example? Presume there is only one field to GET/PUSH to: test_text.

Comment: Excellent that answers my question i think. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See @Tico's answer.

> How do I  (1) Pass through credentials to get a token; (2) Retrieve the Token; (3) Use the token to make a GET and PUSH request?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
    username: "user1",
    password: "testpassword"
    },
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/api-token-auth/',
    success: function(res){
            $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                "token": res.token
              }});
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    test_text: "Testing"
                },
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test/',
                success: function(res){
                    alert(res);
                }});

    }
});
```

Comment: Using the code exactly just returns: `Data:[object Object]`. However if i do `alert("Data: " + data.token` i get a token returned. How do i retrieve and store this in a variable so i can use it later? Doing `var atoken = data.token` yields an empty variable.

Comment: can you tell what your response object structure is.

Answer (score 1):

as post, get or any other url calls are asynchronous calls. So in order to maintain the program flow and make the post request you need to use promise feature of js, which will make your post call synchronous. 
[js promise description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
var data = {username:'user',password:'password'}

$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: data,
       url: 'http://your_url',
       success: function(res){
               console.log(res)
               $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                    "token": res.token
                  }
               });
       },
       error: function(error) {
           callbackErr(error,self)
       }
   })
```

this code will work fine if you use this at the starting of your program, but this is asynchronous, to make it synchronous with your program you need to use promise.
And for the third part of your question you need to do this...

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'http://your_url' + "/token=" + your_token,
       success: function(res){
               console.log(res)
       },
       error: function(error) {
           callbackErr(error,self)
       }
   })
```